# Grease Pencil : How to prevent rounded stroke ends

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I came across a problem while doing 2D animation - I have drawn over the rough sketches of the frames with an ink pen, but I couldn't get the line to end without the end of the line being rounded so it's very difficult to connect one line to the other without having it look awkward. I've tried erasing it but blender only erases the lines in segments instead of that specific part of the line that I want to get rid of.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Blender Version 2.92 Alpha and onward ([Download Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/)) you can use the **Cutter Tool** to remove the caps from your lines.

From [wiki.blender.org](https://wiki.blender.org/w/images/thumb/5/5c/Cutter_Flat_Option.png/600px-Cutter_Flat_Option.png) :
[image]

Patch note : https://developer.blender.org/rB2985a745bb01

Also there is an option to automerge strokes ends while drawing, in which you could be interested.

[image]

Disabled :

[image]

Enabled :

[image]

Patch note :
https://developer.blender.org/rBe9607f45d85d

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this feature till now, haha